# 3-D Vector Fields for Modeling

Tags: matlab

I hope this isn't too general of a question, but I'm having an issue with some syntax in this 3D vector field example provided on Mathworks' website in addition to actually just understanding how to make the 3d vector fields.

I'm trying to create a very robust 3D vector field to model wind patterns based on current NOAA information for a geographic region to predict (or simulate) a path in which a balloon system / parachute system would / should drift on ascent and descent.

In saying that, I'm just starting with the 3D vector fields and the same could be said for 2D vector fields, but I can't seem to find a great resource for the 3D ones.

```
field := plot::VectorField3d([1, sin(x) + cos(y), sin(z)], 
                         x = 0..6, y = 0..2.5, z = 0..5,
                         Mesh = [7, 7, 7]):
```

plot(field):

This is one of the examples, but I'm not familiar with the usage of ".." in succession or the stacking that they seem to have done with the lines. I've tried copying this into a new ".m" file that I created and running it, but I get: "Unexpected MATLAB expression". I've tried guessing at the notation by switching ".." to ":" and the ending ":" to a ";" , but I didn't get anywhere.

If you need me to clarify, let me know, and thanks for reading / helping in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0..6` stands for a range - see http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/uname.html

To run your example, type `mupad` in the command window and paste the example in the mupad editor.